# Execute Anonymous Error: Getting Started with Apex

Tags: apex, trailhead

I am working through the trail head module and have copied the code to create an APEX class to send emails like for like.

```
public class EmailManager {

    // Public method
    public void sendMail(String address, String subject, String body) {
        // Create an email message object
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {address};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        // Pass this email message to the built-in sendEmail method 
        // of the Messaging class
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                                 new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

        // Call a helper method to inspect the returned results
        inspectResults(results);
    }

    // Helper method
    private static Boolean inspectResults(Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results) {
        Boolean sendResult = true;

        // sendEmail returns an array of result objects.
        // Iterate through the list to inspect results. 
        // In this class, the methods send only one email, 
        // so we should have only one result.
        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult res : results) {
            if (res.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Email sent successfully');
            }
            else {
                sendResult = false;
                System.debug('The following errors occurred: ' + res.getErrors());                 
            }
        }

        return sendResult;
    }

}
```

The instructions say to Anonymously execute it with this:

```
EmailManager em = new EmailManager();
em.sendMail('My Email Address', 'Trailhead Tutorial', '123 body');
```

Upon execution , I get the following error:

> **Execute Anonymous Error**
>
> Line: 2, Column: 4 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   sendMail(String, String, String) from the type EmailManager

New to APEX and this is copied verbatim, so confused as to why it isnt working

Comment: Are you sure the class actually saved correctly? This error makes it seem like `EmailManager` failed to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems 100% like a your `EmailManager` failed to compile. Normally you would see errors similar to this one if you declared your method `static` and called it the way you did:

```
// won't work, can't call static method from instance
public class MyClass
{
    public static void myMethod(/*params*/) { /*implementation*/ }
}

// script
new MyClass().myMethod(/*params*/);
```

Or if you declared it an instance method and tried to call it statically:

```
// won't work, can't call instance method statically
public class MyClass
{
    public void myMethod(/*params*/) { /*implementation*/ }
}

// script
MyClass.myMethod(/*params*/);
```